# Slow performance reading parquet files in S3 with scala in Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I save a partitioned file in a s3 bucket from a data frame in scala

`data_frame.write.mode("append").partitionBy("date").parquet("s3n://...")`

When I read this partitioned file I'm experimenting very slow performance, I'm just doing a simple group by

`val load_df = sqlContext.read.parquet(s"s3n://...").cache()`

I also try 
`load_df.registerTempTable("dataframe")`

Any advice, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe append can generate many files and dir, Can you avoid it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "very slow performance".

If you have too many files in you `date` partition it will take some time to read those.

Try to reduce granularity of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the S3A driver (which may be as simple as changing your url protocol to s3a://, or maybe you'll need some extra classpath to have hadoop-aws and aws-sdk jars in it) to have better perfs.